# is there any way to disable or speed up React PropType validation in development mode?

Tags: performance, validation, reactjs, react-proptypes

As far as I know the only way to disable React PropType validation is to uglify React with `process.env.NODE_ENV` defined to be `'production'`.

However, I would like to use development mode without runtime PropType validation for the following reasons:

- They slow down my app significantly.  PropType validation is the top offender in profiling results because:

  - I have a fairly deep component hierarchy with PropType validation at multiple levels (yes I do have proper shouldComponentUpdate etc.)
  - I'm using Redux, which means all updates start at or near the top of the hierarchy
  - I have mouse drag interactions which strive for 30 updates per second
- I still want to see all other React warnings and errors, which would also get disabled in production mode.
- Flowtype can apparently statically validate PropTypes in a lot of cases anyway.

If nothing else I could create a transformer for `babel-plugin-react-transform` that strips away all components' `propTypes` (or perhaps only those of components I've annotated in a certain way), but I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to do it, because React *could* easily provide a compile-time flag to disable PropType validation.

**UPDATE**: that babel plugin already exists (https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-react-remove-prop-types)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: There is no simple flag to disable only PropType validation

---

Currently, PropType validation is enabled by `__DEV__` global variable.
If it's changed to false, you will lose other React warnings and errors that, as you said, you can't.

This code [here in ReactDOMFactories](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/3b96650e39ddda5ba49245713ef16dbc52d25e9e/src/isomorphic/classic/element/ReactDOMFactories.js#L26) shows how `ReactElementValidator` and `ReactElement` factories are chosen to define how an element creation will work:

```
function createDOMFactory(tag) {
  if (__DEV__) {
    return ReactElementValidator.createFactory(tag);
  }
  return ReactElement.createFactory(tag);
}
```

In [ReactElementValidator.createElement](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/3b96650e39ddda5ba49245713ef16dbc52d25e9e/src/isomorphic/classic/element/ReactElementValidator.js#L257) you can see that it calls [ReactElement.createElement](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/3b96650e39ddda5ba49245713ef16dbc52d25e9e/src/isomorphic/classic/element/ReactElement.js#L114) and then [validatePropTypes](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/3b96650e39ddda5ba49245713ef16dbc52d25e9e/src/isomorphic/classic/element/ReactElementValidator.js#L232):

```
var ReactElementValidator = {

  createElement: function(type, props, children) {

    /* some code here */

    var element = ReactElement.createElement.apply(this, arguments);

    /* some code here */

    // here would be a good place for the flag that you need
    validatePropTypes(element);

    return element;
  }
```

I'm not sure how this information can help you but at least shows that there is no simple way to disable PropType by a flag as you wondered.

---

**UPDATE - 10/May/2017**
[Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/200224/andy) found that there is a [Babel Plugin that removes Prop Types](https://github.com/oliviertassinari/babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types).
I hadn't test it. Be sure to read the [Is it safe?](https://github.com/oliviertassinari/babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types#is-it-safe) section of the plugin to see if it fits for you.

Comment: that's cool, I've never read much of React internals, but it's neat that they made element creation pluggable like that.

Comment: I added a note about a babel plugin I found to remove proptypes (https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-react-remove-prop-types)

Comment: I'm not clear now - are they automatically removed from `production` builds, or is the Babel plugin needed?